# class-wise subtracting (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

An experiment was performed in which certain individuals (ID: 1, 2, 3) received multiple treatments (Treatment: A, B, C). The Response variable was recorded three times after eacht treatment (Time: 0, 1, 2). For every combination of ID and Treatment there thus exist 3 outputs.

My data is in the longitudinal format and consists of two objects: datalabel and datamatrix

Datalabel is a 27*3 cell that contains information on the combination of ID, treatment, and Time of the results in the Datamatrix double (27x1).

Datalabel looks like this:

```
   {'1', 'A', '0';
    '1', 'A', '1';
    '1', 'A', '2';
    '1', 'B', '0';
    '1', 'B', '1';

%datapoints in between

    '3', 'C', '1';
    '3', 'C', '2'}
```

Datamatrix looks like this:

```
    [1;3;4;6; 8;  
%datapoints in between
     2;8]
```

What I would like to do is, for every combination of ID and Treatment, subtract the output at time 0 from all three outputs. The result would be a new 27x1 double that looks like this:

```
    [0;2;3;0; 2;
%datapoints in between
    -1;5]
```

In this case it is not too difficult. But I would like to find a generic solution that works no matter how many different levels of 'uur', 'treatment', and 'ID' there are, that works when some animals have not received a certain treatment, and that works when there are missing observations (not for uur=0).

I hope my problem is clear and that someone is able to help,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "subtract the output at time 0 from all three outputs." and how you get the matrix `[0;2;3;0; 2; ...`

Comment: also, your original 27x1 matrix, will all of column 3 always be (0,1,2) repeated? Just to understand

Comment: For every combination of ID and Treatment there exist three responses, at time 0, 1, and 2. I would like to subtract the response at time 0 from the response at time 1 and time 2.

Comment: There exists only one column. The first value in Datamatrix is the response of Animal 1 given Treatment A at time 0. The second value in Datamatrix is the response of Animal 1 given Treatment A at time 1. The thirth value in Datamatrix is the response of Animal 1 given Treatment A at time 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, so just to understand, your whole question, basically, is how to take your 27x1 matrix and subtract the observation (3n + 1)th for n=0:8 observation from the other 2?

Comment: IN the original Datamatrix the first three values are 1, 3 and 4. The value that belongs to time=0 is 1. Therefore I wish to subtract 1 from 1, 3, and 4. Which results in 0, 2, and 3

Comment: Basically, however I need this to also work when for instance the observations for time=2 is missing

Comment: Ok, and if it's missing, you'll have a `0` or what?

Comment: No, than there would be no line for that combination of ID, Treatment, and Time. Therefore sequence-like solutions won't work

Comment: Maybe there exists a function that gives the index of new observed combinations of cell-content in the same row or something?

Comment: I know I'm thinking about this as a programmer, but I have a solution using for loops.... Maybe that could at least point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, as stated in the comments, I haven't used Matlab for a while and I have absolutely no doubt there's nicer ways to do this, but using for loops, I could imagine a solution looking as follows:

```
for val = 1:numel(Datamatrix)
   if Datalabel{val,3} == '0'
      ToSubtract = Datamatrix(val);
   end
   ChangedDataMatrix(val) = Datamatrix(val) - ToSubtract;
end
```

That should:

1. Decide what to subtract based upon the 3rd column of your Datalabel matrix.
2. Pull the value only when it's on test at time 0.
3. Subtract all tests from that value until the next test at time 0 occurs.

Again, I have no doubt this could be done in other ways, but i'm in programming mode now moreso than Matlab, but I hope this does the trick!!

Comment: Thanks, I can work with this! Will implement it tomorrow too check whether this works